# Validating jwt in java: Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures

Tags: java, jwt

I receive the jwt (access token) from an OAuth Server. The OAuth server has already provided me with the secret, public key, and self-signed CA certificate.

I want to write a code that when I receive a jwt, I can validate it and check if this server has sent it to me. I use the following code to validat my jwt in java.

```
String jwt = "xxx.yyy.zzz";

        //This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as expected)
Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(self_signed_CA_Certificate))
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
```

I get the error: `Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures.  Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was my solution

in my case I gad a certificate that give the ability that can be signed with different keys,

```
   CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream ("yourcertificate.jks");
   Certificate cer = fact.generateCertificate(is);
   PublicKey  publicKey = cer.getPublicKey();
```

and then to verify the jwt token used:

```
 Claims body = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(publicKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to create secretKey using RSA like

```
SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey(); 
or 
Key secretKey = MacProvider.generateKey();
```

use same secretKey key to generate jwt string and decrypt it using same secrete key like

```
SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
                  .setSubject("Joe")
                  .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey)
                  .compact();


Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey)
                        .parseClaimsJws(compactJws).getBody();
```

Comment: you don't require to create key again.  did you try with self-signed CA certificate secret key.  if they gave you valid key  it should work. in your code your are try with "secret" which it not a valid RSA key. that why you are getting error.

Comment: I tried what you suggested: Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(self_signed_CA_Certificate)
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();  but still get the same error. Could it be that I should give the encoding? for example sth similar to using DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary?

Comment: self_signed_CA_Certificate is it string or key object? if it id string then you can pass DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary

Comment: It is a string. DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary results in the same error. I removed the string -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- from the certificate, it is Okay right?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, still same error. Dont you think that I should provide the public key somewhere? it is what is error is saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123891/discussion-between-pegah-and-md-ayub-ali-sarker).

Comment: Please, have u found a solution for this error, because I have it too

Comment: Basically a `PublicKey` instance has to be passed to use RSA (asymmetric) signed keypairs - not a `byte[]` representing the secret