# Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance

Tags: java, jwt, rsa

I'm trying to decode a JWT token from my OAUTH server and I'm using examples from the following [website](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java).

I have tried quite a lot self designed solutions but can't solve an issue, I can't decode a RSA public key signed JWT.

The following code

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("<<Oauth server RSA public key>>").parseClaimsJws(keySec.getTokenString());
```

I get the following Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures.  Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you followed the solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39624577/4636715

Comment: @vahdet: That solution is complete nonsense.

Comment: @vahdet - Yes, it actually works to this part Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).   It fails at parseClaimsJws(keySec.getTokenString());

Comment: Found the solution http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/19/validate-and-process-jwt-tokens-with-java/